# How to escape user-provided text as RTF in Qt4 before using it in eg. QMessageBox?

Tags: html, qt, escaping, rtf, qmessagebox

I recently discovered that QMessageBox parses provided text as HTML subset. I want to use it along with user-provided text (name for an item). How should I escape user's text to prevent interpreting it as RTF/HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Qt::escape(const QString& plain)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt.html#escape) function to escape HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QMessageBox::setTextFormat(Qt::PlainText)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#textFormat-prop) to force it to interpret the text as plain text.